# Suggested ways to handle object persistence on Android activity recreation

Tags: android, android-activity

In my Android application there are many instances where multiple activities call a common service passing it a callback 
Now if the activity is destroyed and recreated (say due to orientation change) then there is every chance that the callback reference is lost. 
I know the normal ways of using onsavedinstance method or an headless fragment of persisting.
But in that Way all my activities have to handle it.  Is there any common way to handle this.

Note : I just want to have a simple and reusable code for the persistence to happen

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to have a simple and reusable code for the persistence to happen

You can create an activity class where you would write all the state management boilerplate code and then make other activities inherit from this base activity.